# Does this prove that the factorial grows faster than the exponential?

Tags: limits, solution-verification, proof-writing, exponential-function, factorial

I want to prove that the factorial grows faster than the exponential function.
First, I introduce the ratio
$$L = \frac{n!}{e^n}.$$
Then, I introduce another ratio :
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{e^{n+1}} = \frac{(n+1) \cdot n!}{e \cdot e^n}
    = \frac{(n+1)}{e} L.$$
When the value of $n$ take values bigger and bigger and $L$ gets bigger and bigger.
In other words,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)}{e} = \infty,$$
meaning that $L$ is divergent. Thus $n!$ grows faster than the exponential.

Comment: Yes, your idea is exactly right, but you need to give $L$ a better name, which depends on $n$ (like $L_n$).

Answer (score 4):

$$
\frac{n!}{e^n} = \prod_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{e}.
$$
Since
$$
\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{i}{e} = \infty,
$$
clearly the factorial is growing faster than the exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method shows specifically that $n!=\omega(e^n)$, since $L_n\to\infty$. There is nothing special about $e$ here, so you can use the same idea to show that $n!=\omega(\alpha^n)$ for any $\alpha$ (or to put it another way, $n!=\omega(e^{\beta n})$ for any $\beta$).